# Best way to retrieve CurrentUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, nancy, owin

When using MVC5 and Nancy on OWIN, what would you consider the best way to consistently retrieve the CurrentUser/Principal?  DependencyInjection aside through the various controllers/modules, there are times that I need the current authenticated user.  In the past, I have used HttpContext.Current.User.  Is Thread.Current an option?  How would you do it?  Trying to set up something consistent for my framework.

Comment: Why are you using MVC and Nancy together?!?

Comment: What I was looking at was actually Katana - I thought it was MVC5.  My bad :(